# How do I force Spring framework to use my logging framework?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I use Spring framework (not Spring Boot) version 5.

How do I force Spring framework to use my logging framework, for example log4j2?

I placed log4j2.xml on the classpath.

I placed the following JARs on the classpath:

log4j-api-2<...>

log4j-core-2<...>

log4j-web-2<...>

log4j-jcl-2<...>

log4j-jul-2<...>

log4j-slf4j-impl-2<...>

sjf4j-api-1.7.25

jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25

commons-logging-1.2

Spring still ignores the log4j2.xml settings, and outputs to StdErr on the console.

Comment: log4j and log4j2 are completely separate systems.

Answer (score 0):

Removed commons-logging-1.2 JAR from the classpath.